# CMIS query: JSON representation of the results of the query

Tags: cmis

[This](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/errata01/os/CMIS-v1.1-errata01-os-complete.html#x1-57300012) documentation references [this document](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/browser/201103/queryResultList) as source for the JSON Query result representation, but the URL appears to be no longer valid.

Does anyone know where I can gather this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is not pointing to document. It is references an element in this schema document: https://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/errata01/os/schema/cmis-browserbinding.orderly